# AWS Elastic Beanstalk mod_wsgi "compiled for" version different than "runtime" version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I'm seeing the following error when I run my Pyramid application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

```
[Thu Jul 21 03:45:20.629134 2016] [:warn] [pid 5232] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9.
[Thu Jul 21 03:45:20.629139 2016] [:warn] [pid 5232] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.10.
```

Anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 1):

If you compile *mod_wsgi*, you need to point the configure script to the appropriate Python binary. For example:

```
wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
make
make install
```

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't do anything myself. It was all set up by elastic beanstalk.

Comment: If you want finer tuned control, you could use the elastic beanstalk *docker* option, or report the inconsistency to AWS.